# Python solve_ivp event-function

Tags: python, events, ode

in my following code i am trying to describe a trajectory from the cathode ray tube.
For my Ode i want to write an event-function which stops the integration when the electron is hitting the screen at x-Position (y[0]) = 0.15.
I tried to set the x-velocity on zero when its happening so the event can work.
But there is some kind of mistake and i wanted to ask how i can write an event-function which stops the integration exactly at y[0]=0.15

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def trajectory(t,y,U_A,e,d,m_e):
    # Zur Übersichtlichkeit:
    # y[0] - x-position
    # y[1] - x-velocity
    # y[2] - y-position
    # y[3] - y-velocity
    dx2dt2 = 0
    if y[0]==(l_s+s):
        dxdt = 0
    else:
        dxdt = y[1]
    if 0<y[0]<s:
        d2ydt2 = U_A*e/(d*m_e)
    else:
        d2ydt2 = 0
    dydt = y[3]
    return dxdt, dx2dt2, dydt , d2ydt2

def hit_screen(t,y,*args):
    
    return y[1]
    
hit_screen.terminal = True
hit_screen.direction = -1

d=0.005
s=0.05
l_r=l_s=0.1
U_A = 100 #V
U_B = 300 #V
m_e = 9.1*10**(-31) #kg
e = 1.6*10**(-19) #C
v_x = np.sqrt(2*U_B*e/m_e)
a_y = U_A*e/(d*m_e)

#Anfangswerte definieren:    
x0 = -l_r # m
v_x0 = v_x # m/s
y0 = 0
v_y0 = 0
t_eval = np.linspace(0,2.5*10**(-5),1000) # Zeitbereich der Integriert werden soll (in s)
maxStep=t_eval[1]/1000 
startvec = [x0, v_x0,y0,v_y0] # Anfangswert für Weg und Geschwindigkeit
sol = solve_ivp(trajectory,t_eval,startvec,args=(U_A,e,d,m_e),max_step=maxStep,events=(hit_screen))
t = sol.t
x = sol.y[0,:]
v_x1 = sol.y[1,:]
y=sol.y[2,:]

#Werte plotten
plt.plot(x,y);
plt.axis( [-0.125, 0.175, -0.4, 0.4] )
x1 = np.linspace(0,0.05,100)
y2 = U_A*e/(2*d*m_e)*(x1/v_x)**2
plt.plot(x1,y2,'r');
```

The following plot is looking like this
[plot-cathoderraytube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIrUM.png)

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Setting the x-derivative to zero does not automatically result in a zero x-velocity in the next step. Indeed, that change in the first component has no automatic influence on the second component, there is no automatic coupling. You generate this semantic context by the structure of the first order system. The solver just ignores this background.

There is a much more direct way to define this event,

```
def hit_screen(t,y,*args):
    
    return y[0]-(l_s+s)
```